# Dynamic template for a ComboBox in ListBox

Tags: wpf, xaml, combobox

I have a ListBox with an embedded ComboBox:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding}">
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <ComboBox Width="100" IsEditable="False" Height="20">
            <TextBlock Text="Opt#1"></TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Text="Opt#2"></TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Text="Opt#3"></TextBlock>
        </ComboBox>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

I'd like to present the ComboBox as a simple text (e.g. TextBlock) when a ListBox row is not selected, and show it as a ComboBox when the ListBox row is selected.

I was thinking that replacing ComboBox template dynamically would do the trick. How to accomplish that?

Thanks,
Leszek

Answer (score 0):

The best way to swap templates is to use the ItemTemplateSelector propery of the ListBox and set it to a class you create which inherits from DataTemplateSelector.

Here is a link that provides an example:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datatemplateselector.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I would simply use a style that replace the `ListBox.ItemTemplate` whenever the `ListBoxItem` becomes selected.

Here's a quick example

```
<ListBox.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="TextBoxTemplate">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding }" />
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="ComboBoxTemplate">
        <ComboBox SelectedItem="{Binding }">
            <ComboBoxItem>Opt#1</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem>Opt#2</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem>Opt#3</ComboBoxItem>
        </ComboBox>
    </DataTemplate>

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
        <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource TextBoxTemplate}" />
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource ComboBoxTemplate}" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</ListBox.Resources>
```

I'd actually suggest using `IsKeyboardFocusWithin` instead of `IsSelected` as the trigger property, because templates can let you interact with them without setting the item as selected.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Josh and Rachel for pointing me in a right direction.

I came up with a solution similar to the one suggested by Rachel. My problem was I could not make ItemTemplateSelector work and I did not know how to pass the state IsSelected from my listbox. I also could not use DataTemplate because my ListBox item is much more complex than a single element (I simplified it in my previous post for the sake of example).

Anyway, I came up with the following solution. It's not very elegant but it works:

1. I defined a new style in Application resources:

   ```
   <Style x:Key="TextBlockTemplate" TargetType="ComboBox">
       <Setter Property="Template">
           <Setter.Value>
               <ControlTemplate>
                   <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" Margin="3" />
               </ControlTemplate>
           </Setter.Value>
       </Setter>
   </Style>
   ```
2. I attached SelectionChanged and PreviewMouseDown handlers to my ListBox:
3. I defined MyListBox_PreviewMouseDown:

```
    private void MyListBox_PreviewMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        // Grab the selected list box item.
        object element = (e.OriginalSource as FrameworkElement).DataContext;
        var item = MyListBox.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(element) 
            as ListBoxItem;

        // Mark the row in the ListBox as selected.
        if (item != null)
            item.IsSelected = true;
    }
```

1. I defined MyListBox_SelectionChanged:

```
    private ComboBox prevComboBox = null;
    private void MyListBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Grab the list box.
        ListBox list = sender as ListBox;

        // Although there could be only one item selected, 
        // we iterate over all selected items.
        foreach (MyDataItem dat in list.SelectedItems)
        {
            var item = list.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(dat) as ListBoxItem;
            // FindElement is a helper method to find an element in a visual tree.
            ComboBox cbo = FindElement(item, "MyComboBox") as ComboBox;

            if (cbo != prevComboBox)
            {
                cbo.Style = null;

                if (prevComboBox != null)
                    prevComboBox.Style = 
                        (Style)Application.Current.Resources["TextBlockTemplate"];

                prevComboBox = cbo;
            }
        }
    }
```

Thanks,
Leszek